# Trying to mysql group concat elements from 3 different tables

Tags: mysql

Im having trouble making a single mysql query that groups some items..

Visualized is this:

Table Show:

| ID | Movie | IndexID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This | 1234 |
| 2 | That | 1235 |

Table Show_index

| IndexID | Genre_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2 |
| 1234 | 3 |
| 1235 | 1 |
| 1235 | 4 |

Table Show_genres

| Genre_ID | Genre_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | One |
| 2 | Two |
| 3 | Three |
| 4 | Four |

How do I get a mysql query that shows me this?

| Show | Genres |
| --- | --- |
| This | Two,Three |
| That | One,Four |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `group by` and `group_concat()` :

```
select Movie as `show`, group_concat(Genre_Name) as Genres
from `show` s
inner join Show_index i on s.IndexID = i.IndexID
inner join Show_genres g on g.Genre_ID = i.Genre_ID
group by ID, Movie
order by ID
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DBX6QQha)